# How to rename subfolders by copying the name of the file in the subfolder?

Tags: python, subdirectory, file-rename

I'm trying to rename subfolders based on an a file name in the folder. I would like the folder name and file name to be the same. Currently I have a script that loops through all the subfolders and renames the files to the correct name. Now i need to take that "correct name" and rename the subfolder that file is in with the same name.

The current set up of the directory:

```
Folder A(Parent folder)

    Folder sample1(Sub folder)
       1. sample.pdf
       2. correct_name1.xml

    Folder B2(Sub folder)
       1. sample.pdf
       2. correct_name2.xml

    Folder B3(Sub folder)
       1. sample.pdf
       2. correct_name3.xml
```

Expected output:

```
 correct_name1 B1(Sub folder)
       1. correct_name1.pdf
       2. correct_name1.xml

    correct_name2 B2(Sub folder)
       1. correct_name2.pdf
       2. correct_name2.xml

    correct_name3 B3(Sub folder)
       1. correct_name3.pdf
       2. correct_name3.xml
```

Also if someone could help with renaming the pdf file as well that would be appreciated. The pdf file would be the exact same name as the xml.

I tried adding this inside the if statement, but it didn't rename the subfolders.

```
for dir in dirs:
     sub_folder = os.path.join(path,curr_fld,dir)
     print(sub_folder)
     os.rename(sub_folder,new_name2)
```

My code:

```
def rename(path)
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            curr_fld = os.path.basename(root)
            old_name = os.path.join(path,curr_fld,file)

            if file.endswith(".xml"): 
                file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(file)
                print(file_name)

                new_name = "{}-{}-{}-{}{}".format(cfr, year, title, item_id, file_ext) # this is what i had done originally to get the correct file name
                new_name2 = os.path.join(path,curr_fld,new_name) #my correct name

                try:
                    os.rename(old_name,new_name2) 
                except WindowsError:
                     print("Didn't work!")
```

Comment: Please show the final expected file structure as well. From what I understand it cannot be done, as there cannot be multiple folders with the ame name in the same place

Comment: I added the expected output. each folder would have a different name because each file in the folder is a different name.  I hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `root` as the directory to rename if the `files` list contains an `.xml` file:

```
def rename(path):
    for root, _, files in os.walk(path):
        try:
            new_name, _ = next(os.path.splitext(file) for file in files if file.endswith('.xml'))
        except StopIteration:
            continue
        os.rename(root, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(root), new_name))
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked, I really appreciate it. I think making it another function made it easier than that long function i wrote.